# Nearly every app I open directly crashes

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, crashes, system-apps, google-apps

As specified in the title my problem is only that. Any app I open in my phone crashes with the message "Unfortunately the app has stopped working".

Only the Google apps, Edge browser, Camera and Whatsapp are not crashing rest all apps are crashing on opening.

This started happening without any change. I left my phone in a good normal condition and after an hour when I came back it showed "unfortunately truecaller has stopped working". I also tried opening games but they also kept crashing. No use of restarting or switching off and on. I've done that literally a hundreds of times.

My phone is not rooted. Just a normal phone running Android 6. Please help me fast.

Comment: Hi @Robert !. Luckily I fixed the problem when I uninstalled all updates from "Android System Web View" Application in the settings app. After that BOOM. All my problems just flew away. I don't know how this problem originated but now I have fixed it. :)

Comment: Better try to install the Webview updates again otherwise all apps that use WebView will be vulnerable and might cause malware to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Alike the asker, uninstalling / removing updates of Android System WebView app fixed the problem for me too.